# Creating a LSTM Neural Network outputting two Y variables

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

I have a classification task based on Tweets. The Tweets are my only input (X) variable. I have two target (y) variables however, one target variable should output 1 or 0 for either positive or negative, while the other target variable should output 1 or 0 for either political or non-political.

I created a LSTM neural network which is running, but I can't seem to get it to output two target variables. Can somebody please advise?

My input shapes are:

```
X_train        y_train
(15203, 250) (15203, 2)
X_val         y_val
(3801, 250) (3801, 2)
```

My model is:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=X.shape[1]))
    model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
    
    # For two label classification
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I noticed I was not getting two target variables when I later ran this piece of code on unseen data

```
    new_text = ["Tony Gonzales (@TonyGonzales4TX) will be a GREAT Congressman for Texas! A Navy veteran, he is Strong on the Economy, Life and the Second Amendment. We need him to defeat the Radical Left in November. Tony has my Complete and Total Endorsement! #TX23"]
    seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(new_text)
    padded = pad_sequences(seq, maxlen = 250)
    pred = model.predict(padded)
    labels = [0,1]
    print(pred, labels[np.argmax(pred)])
```

On this and all other tests, I noticed my predictions were only returning a binary classification. e.g. on the above I got 0.13   0.87 (these figures add up to 100 so are tied together)

However, in the above case, a positive political Tweet, I would have expected a dual result of circa 0.88  0.91

Any help would on how to get two output y variables would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add 4 nodes in your output layer representing (negative, positive, political, non-political)
and map you ytrain in that manner
or you can try this:

```
x = your input numpy array
y1 = your sentiment one hot encoded output numpy array
y2 = your political one hot encoded output numpy array
# x, y1, y2 should have same length or shape[0]
data = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, [y1, y2]))
data = data.shuffle(len(x))

input =  Input(shape=(X.shape[1], ))
x = Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=X.shape[1])(input)
x = SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(x)
x = LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)(x)
out1 = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='sentiment')(x)
out2 = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='political')(x)
model = Model(inputs = input, outputs=[out1, out2])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(data, other arguments....]  #supposing your output is one hot encoded
```

[image]

See if it works or not.

Comment: Wow thank you, that is very thorough work! It seems to be working fine right down as far as `model.fit`.  Here I receive an error of `ValueError: Layer sentiment was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.` Both my `xtrain` and `ytrain` are numpy 2d arrays of type float32. Any ideas what this could be? Should it be `model.fit(X_train, [y_train, y_train])` I'm guessing?

Comment: You're a gentleman, thank you very much. I would have never gotten this in a million years! Thanks for the effort you put in.

Comment: Arent you really just doing 2 one-hot encoded y variables, so you're Y will have shape (n,4)? if so you just use np.hstack((y1,y2)) where y1 and y2 are each one-hot encoded arrays. note for it to work properly depending on your data y1 and y2 may have to be reshaped to (n,2). I was working through the same issue and think the @CiaranOBrien may be making the mistake of thinking of two Y inputs as two different streams of inputs. in reality a one-hot encoded Y is already some dummy variables, so with two topics, you are just adding more.

Comment: @Vlox I will admit this was so long ago I have forgotten what I was thinking! I do know I have always considered all my X and Y data as one input. It was the issue with my outputs I had problems with. i.e. splitting my outputs into two distinct results. I'm not entirely sure it is one-hot encoding as the Embedding function creates a dense vector from the X input, meaning most of the values are non 0. The Y values are Tokenised which returns a vector of non 0 values as 0 is used for padding.